# HTML seems to not register me trying to connect an external CSS

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a ton. Yet I cant get mine to work after spending 2+ hours and downloading debugging software. I cant get my HTML file to link with CSS. One is a pic of HTML with the site I am trying to use. The other is my CSS. Sorry if this is actually an incredibly easy fix. I am  student. Thanks for any help.

[image: HTML]

[image: CSS]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Post CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: Press F12 and look in the network tab to see if the css file is actually found where it is expected

Comment: You have to share your project structure as well. Assuming style.css is in the same directory, try this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"`